# django-tables2 dynamic columns

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-tables2

Is it possible to make dynamic columns in a table using django-tables2? I have a model which contains all the columns which have to be in the table, and the data which should be under the columns all have a foreign key to a column.

```
class Data(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField()
    column = models.ForeignKey(Column)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Column(models.Model):
    header = models.CharField()
```

So the far left column of the table should be User and the next columns should all be the columns in Column.objects.all(), then the data is under the column object it has the foreign key to.

I hope you can help!

Comment: I dnt understand by the term "dynamic column". and you want to render data in columns which has foreign key relation to another column??

Comment: Well by dynamic column I mean that all the columns are loaded from the database. Let's say there is a column A1 in the database. There is another table with column data and if it has a foreign key with column A1 is should go in the A1 column in the table. I hope that helps..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify the columns of a table at runtime rather than at programming time, you can use the class below:

## tables.py

```
import django_tables2 as tableslib

class DynamicColumnsTable(tableslib.Table):

    def __init__(self, *args, column_specs=(), **kwargs):
        bc = type(self.base_columns)(self.base_columns) # clone                                                                                                          
        for name, column in column_specs:
            self.base_columns[name] = column
        tableslib.Table.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) # refers to static spec                                                                                          
        type(self).base_columns = bc # restore static spec
```

Example usage:

## views.py

```
import django.shortcuts as shortcuts
import django_tables2 as tableslib

def test(request):
    data = [
        {"name": "Bobo"},
        {"name": "Gogo"},
    ]

    djtable = DynamicColumnsTable(column_specs=(  ('name', tableslib.Column()),  ),
                                  data=data)
    return shortcuts.render(request, 'test.html', {'djtable': djtable})
```

Answer (score 0):

The Table should look like this:

```
class ABC(tables.Table):  
      user= tables.Column(accessor='user.username')
      column= tables.Column(accessor= 'column.header')  
      data= tables.Column(accessor='data')


    class Meta:
       model = Data
       sequence= ('user', 'column', 'data')
```

Details: http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#specifying-alternative-data-for-a-column

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, I added some code to make it more clear.

Comment: The problem is that there are more then one column in the Column.objects.all(). All the <th> attributes should be the column objects header. It's difficult and maybe I shouldn't use django-tables2 but just do it myself. Thanks anyway

Comment: using `accessor` may make your problem easier to solve. you can create multiple columns with accessors like `column_footer=tables.Column(accessor='column.footer')`